# Nao consigo inserir em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: php, sql-insert, mysqli

Estou com problemas. Eu insiro normalmente na tabela "equipamento" do meu codigo e populo normalmente o BD mysql.

Contudo, a tabela "dell" fica vazia, mesmo passando a referencia da ID da tabela "equipamento". Pelo phpmyadmin esta tudo funcionando normalmente, se eu inserir por lá funciona, mas eu tenho que fazer via PHP no mysqli.

"equipamento" é independente e "dell" é uma tabela dependente com FK_item que é auto_increment

Ajuda!!!

```
<?php
//tabela dell
$fabricante=$_POST['fabricante'];
$modelo=$_POST['modelo'];
$tipo=$_POST['tipo'];
$data=date("Y/m/d");
$url=$_POST['url'];
$serie=$_POST['serie'];
$proprietario=$_POST['proprietario'];
$origem=$_POST['origem'];
$venc_garantia=date("Y/m/d");
$tipo_instalacao=$_POST['tipo_instalacao'];
$configuracao=$_POST['configuracao'];
$uname_a=$_POST['uname_a'];
$instalacao=$_POST['instalacao'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$servicos=$_POST['servicos'];

//tabela equipamento
$descricao=$_POST['descricao'];
$quantidade=$_POST['quantidade'];
$tombamento=$_POST['tombamento'];
$local=$_POST['local'];

//tabela equipamento
$query = "INSERT INTO equipamento (item, tipo, descricao, quantidade, tombamento, local, status)
VALUES(NULL, '$tipo', '$descricao', '$quantidade', '$tombamento', '$local','$status')";

$mysqli->query($query);
printf ("Registro de id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
//tabela dell
$query2 = "INSERT INTO dell (id_item, fabricante, modelo, tipo, data, url, serie, proprietario, origem, venc_garantia, tipo_instalacao,
configuracao, uname_a, instalacao, servicos, tombamento) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$fabricante', '$modelo', 
'$tipo', '$data', '$url', '$serie', '$proprietario', '$origem', '$venc_garantia', '$tipo_instalacao', '$configuracao', 
'$uname_a', '$instalacao', '$status', '$servicos', '$tombamento')";
$mysqli->query($query2);
printf("Novo Registro foi inserido com sucesso\n"); 
printf ("Registro de id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO dell (id_item, fabricante, modelo, tipo, data, url, serie,      proprietario, origem, venc_garantia, tipo_instalacao,
configuracao, uname_a, instalacao, servicos, tombamento) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),     '$fabricante', '$modelo', 
'$tipo', '$data', '$url', '$serie', '$proprietario', '$origem', '$venc_garantia',     '$tipo_instalacao', '$configuracao', 
'$uname_a', '$instalacao', '$status', '$servicos', '$tombamento')";
```

Nesta sua segunda QUERY nos campos para inserir tem um campo que não está mapeado que é o STATUS.

Verifique isso que provavelmente é o motivo.

Substitua por essa:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO dell (id_item, fabricante, modelo, tipo, data, url, serie,      proprietario, origem, venc_garantia, tipo_instalacao,
configuracao, uname_a, instalacao, status, servicos, tombamento) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),     '$fabricante', '$modelo', 
'$tipo', '$data', '$url', '$serie', '$proprietario', '$origem', '$venc_garantia',     '$tipo_instalacao', '$configuracao', 
'$uname_a', '$instalacao', '$status', '$servicos', '$tombamento')";
```

Comment: vou testar aki e jaja retorno o resultado.

Comment: E ai, deu certo cara?

Comment: deu sim. eu colokei positivo no seu comentario, mas acho que o site nao registrou. Vlw mesmo o auxilio e apoio. Me ajudaram mesmo. Sabe me sugerir algum programa bom pra eu nao cometer esses erros? estou usando o notepad++ pra fazer esses meus codigos :/

Comment: Aperta na setinha pra cima ao lado do meu comentário e marca como resposta certa se puder! O recomendado é você fazer isso em alguma IDE...você pode baixar ou o NetBeans (Para PHP) ou o Eclipse (Para PHP). Os dois vão funcionar tranquilo com seu projeto!

Comment: coloquei a setinha ja. nao posso é dar um "up" pq não tenho 15 de reputação. Obrigado pelo apoio aew Dante. Abraços!

Comment: Nada cara, disponha sempre! \o

Answer (score 0):

No **INSERT INTO dell...** percebi que você está inserindo 17 valores em 16 campos. O número de campos deve ser exatamente igual ao número de valores passados no **VALUES**. Pode ser este o motivo do problema.

Acredito que você tenha esquecido do campo STATUS (perceba que ele está no VALUES mas não está na lista de campos da tabela).

Tente assim:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO dell (id_item, fabricante, modelo, tipo, data, url, serie, proprietario, origem, venc_garantia, tipo_instalacao,
configuracao, uname_a, instalacao, status, servicos, tombamento) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(), '$fabricante', '$modelo', 
'$tipo', '$data', '$url', '$serie', '$proprietario', '$origem', '$venc_garantia', '$tipo_instalacao', '$configuracao', 
'$uname_a', '$instalacao', '$status', '$servicos', '$tombamento')";
```

Comment: vou testar aki e jaja retorno o resultado.

Comment: deu sim. eu colokei positivo no seu comentario, mas acho que o site nao registrou. Vlw mesmo o auxilio e apoio. Me ajudaram mesmo. Sabe me sugerir algum programa bom pra eu nao cometer esses erros? estou usando o notepad++ pra fazer esses meus codigos :/